# Abstract class : Why newInstance() is not giving compilation error but constructor call gives error?

Tags: java, abstract-class, instantiation, instanceof

Compiler knows that `AbstractDemo` is an abstract class and Abstract classes can't be instantiated.

But when I call `newInstance()` method, why it did not give a compile time error?

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;

public abstract class AbstractDemo{
    public AbstractDemo(){
        System.out.println("Default constructor");
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        try{
            /* No compilation error for this statement */
            AbstractDemo demo = AbstractDemo.class.newInstance(); 

            Constructor[] ctors = AbstractDemo.class.getDeclaredConstructors();
            for ( int i=0; i < ctors.length; i++){
                System.out.println(ctors[i]);
                /* No compilation error for this statement too */
                AbstractDemo demo1 = (AbstractDemo) ctors[i].newInstance();
            }
            /* Compilation error here */
            // AbstractDemo demo2 = new AbstractDemo(); 
        }catch(Exception err){
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Output when I ran this program: ( I know that error will come since I can't create instance for abstract class. But why it was not given at compile time is surprising me)

```
D:\Study\Java>java AbstractDemo

java.lang.InstantiationException
        at sun.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.java:48)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
        at AbstractDemo.main(AbstractDemo.java:10)
```

**EDIT:**

***Compiler is intelligent to give error for this statement:***

```
AbstractDemo demo2 = new AbstractDemo();
```

***But not for this statement***

```
AbstractDemo demo = AbstractDemo.class.newInstance();
```

Am I missing any key lesson here?

Comment: What happens at runtime? How can the compiler know that the `Constructor` object is related to an abstact class?

Comment: [The documentation says:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance()) *Use of this method effectively bypasses the compile-time exception checking that would otherwise be performed by the compiler*

Comment: Key lesson: the compiler isn't capable of preventing you from writing broken code.

Comment: @Titus That part is actually referring to constructors that throw checked exceptions.

Comment: @Kayaman oh, you're right, that is mentioned in the next line

Comment: Compilation errors are printed, not thrown. Exceptions are thrown, at runtime. Don't misuse standard terminology.

Comment: Nice catch. Sorry for my  bad English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler's job is to check compile-time rules (er, and compile the code). The method you're calling is `Class#newInstance`, not anything related (directly) to `AbstractDemo`. The fact that `Class#newInstance` will throw (because the instance of `Class` on which you call it is for an abstract class) is a runtime concern.

While it might, in theory, be possible *sometimes* to determine at compile-time that a particular reference to a particular instance of `Class` refers to an abstract class (such as `AbstractDemo.class`), usually it won't be possible, for instance:

```
void someMethodInMyOwnClass(Class c) {
    Object o = c.newInstance();
}
```

And even if it were, then we'd need some kind of built-in rule or annotation system (e.g., compile-time information) saying "This method of this class can't be called if the `Class` instance refers to an abstract class."

So we're talking about non-trivial work, and there's no real value in doing that work, making it sometimes a compile-time error and other times a runtime error.

Consider: The compiler could also work out that this throws an NPE:

```
String s = null;
if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("foo")) {
    // ...
}
```

Or that the body of this loop will never be executed:

```
int x = 10;
while (x < 10) {
    System.out.println("Never gets here");
}
```

But we don't have it do so; those are runtime concerns.

Comment: The fact that something isn’t always detectable, is not a sound reasoning why it is ignored when it is detectable. Your last example is a good one. Change the declaration of `x` to `final` and there will be a compiler error. The point is not whether something can be detected or not, but just what has been put into the specification.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler has no static information about what class a given `Constructor` instance is associated with.  With your particular code, a smart enough compiler could figure it out, but because that analysis cannot be performed in general, and therefore cannot be relied upon, compilers are not required to perform it.  I don't know any that do perform it.

Note, however, that the `newInstance()` invocation will fail *at run time*, by throwing an `InstantiationException`.  That is, in fact, the sole and express purpose of that exception class.

When you attempt to instantiate an abstract class directly, however, the compiler knows exactly what class you are instantiating, and that it is abstract, so it can and must reject the code at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

The `newInstance()` method exists on the `Class` class.  Since AbstractDemo.class is just an instance of class (and not a subclass of `Class`), there is no way for the compiler to enforce this.  The thing to know here is that when you use reflection, you are metaprogramming and can't really count on the compiler for much.

To point this out a different way, cosider this code:

```
Class clazz = AbstractDemo.class;
// code that could possibly re-assign clazz here
Object o = clazz.newInstance();
```

Short of running the code, there is no way to know what the `clazz` variable could contain when `newInstance()` is called.  So there is no way for the compiler to flag this.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking to create a class at runtime not at compile time.

The `newInstance` method will throw an `InstantiationException` at runtime in this case.